# fadeOut and fadeIn jquery

Tags: jquery

im new to jquery and im trying to fadeOut and fadeIn some content on scroll.

Here is my example

```
<p class="fade"> lorem blah blah blah </p>
```

and here is my jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('.fade').scroll(function(){
    $('.fade').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $('.fade').fadeIn(500);
    });
    });

});
```

Im getting no console errors from my console but my content isnt fading back in. I belive i am using the scroll function wrong, but im too new to this stuff, thanks for all the help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j9ahfuz4/ Do you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you didn't intend for the scroll event to only apply to the paragraph, this works. I suspect the problem you had was that your paragraph wasn't set up to scroll itself. Your code worked as it is in that case.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { ...
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9wktuh0p/)**

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i wanted, Can you breakdown your solution for me tho, then ill accept it as the answer!!

Comment: Does that make sense? Simply put, unless your paragraph itself has scrollbars, there will be no scroll event thrown on it.

Comment: hmm, for some reason this isnt working for me. My element fadeout but doesnt fade back in still

Comment: Obviously it works in my demo, so there must be something else at play. Please create your own demo with all relevant code.

Comment: my fade class was already being used this whole time...... thanks anyways tho lmfao

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery site:

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set
>   to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less
>   than the height or width of its contents).

So this will apply to your `p` element if it was "scrollable" (user can scroll to a different place in it). You can make it so by adding the *overflow: auto - scroll* to it. If you don't want this, then you should bind this event to the entire document.

```
.fade
{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b0spyg40/